# Does Windows treat the disabling of a USB port with a device connected the same as if the device had been physically removed from the port?

Tags: windows, usb

I would like to simulate the scenario where a USB device is physically removed from a port, however, I am not entirely certain whether Windows will treat the scenario of disabling the port in exactly the same manner as the sudden and unexpected removal of the physical device.

If the behavior is not identical, how do they differ?

Answer (score 0):

Windows would disable a USB port only in the case of catastrophic failure to communicate, when a device would fail to respond with proper protocol after three attempts of a transaction (usually set in hardware). If the port error occurs, the controller will transition to "disabled state", See Section 11.5.1 of USB 2.0 Specifications.
Then the host software will try to reset the port if it is still connected (maintains D+ = high), and if the reset doesn't recover the communication three or four times, the port/device will be assumed as dead, and no more attempts will be made.

In case of "surprise removal" of a device the scenario is different: the port will sense a "disconnect" event. If in HS mode, the termination will be lost, and dual-amplitude reflection will set the disconnect flag during elongated EOP phase of SOF packet. In LS/FS mode the port has a timer that detects the state of "single-ended zero", aka "SE0". If the cable/device is gone, the SE0 line state will stay for longer than 2.5 us, and again the disconnect status will be reported to host. See Section 11.5.2.

If a disconnect is detected, the port will automatically transition into "disconnected state". Then, if the pull-up is really lost due to physical disconnect, the port will time-out into "disabled" state. Since there should be a "disconnect" interrupt" instead of "port error/transaction error" interrupt, the host won't do any attempts to communicate with this port. See Figure 11-10 for the downstream port state diagram, and following descriptions of the states.